# Listen music from OneDrive

Tags: music-player, onedrive

I've a Samsung Galaxy A8 phone (android 8.0.0) and it's connected to my OneDrive accounts (both personal and business) where I store music.

I've tried downloading music to my phone, but I could only make the files available off-line, no proper download.

I've Google Play Music and Samsung Music installed, neither can browse OneDrive off-line files. I can play them with a very basic player (probably skin of one of before mentioned players?), but that's not a solution for me.

How can I listen to music from OneDrive?

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried downloading music to my phone, but I could only make the files available off-line, no proper download

To download music from Onedrive follow the steps below:

1. Click on the 3-dots next to the music file.

   [image: IMG:]
2. A menu with options appears. Select `Save`.

   [image: IMG:]
3. You will be taken to the folder where the file will be downloaded. As seen on the picture below, the default folder is `Download`. You can select another folder by clicking the arrow on the left. Click `Save` on the top right to start the download.

   [image: IMG:]

> How can I listen to music from OneDrive?

To listen directly from OneDrive, click on your music file, then <kbd>►</kbd>. The music file will be streamed online.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works for small number of files as I've "save" option for files only, but not for folders. Is there a way to save folders too?

Comment: Only "Keep offline" is available for Folders as far as I know, and you must have the "Premium" license(?) to use the option.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Use FolderSync to sync  or download the folder..

Comment: @AndroidQuesito thanks for the tip! I wouldn't think I need another app for that... You might add it as an answer as it solved my problem.

Comment: This does not work on Microsoft Android Surface Duo.
One drive advertising for Premium blocks Save feature.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the OneSync app from the google store. It allows you to create a sync for your local (phone) folder with the onedrive's cloud location and keep the files locally in sync.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of apps available for this, I wrote up a few here: https://www.blisshq.com/music-library-management-blog/2021/02/10/comparison-best-cloud-music-players/

Disclaimer alert: I can comment on [Astiga](https://asti.ga) as I operate that service. We made available a free, no-install OneDrive music player: https://asti.ga/onedrive-music-player .

1. Go to the page and *Connect to OneDrive*:

[image]

2. Sign in on Microsoft's site:

[image]

3. Once you've signed in, the music player's page will reload and show your folders:

[image]

4. Find your music and play!

[image]

It only allows browsing of your folders, playback of files, shuffling, repeats etc. To get the full "music library" experience you need to sign up. Let me know if you have any questions!